# Removing Masshead Magento Extension from certain categories

Tags: magento

As I describe in the title, what i want to do is to remove the Masshead extension from certain categories in magento. Any ideas how can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

The module will be most likely including a block on the categories page. This block will be defined in the modules layout xml file. You need to find the definition to identify the name of the block and the name of the parent block/container it is being included in. As you want to keep it on some categories but remove it from others, the simplest solution I can think of would to be to use Magento's Administration Area for the categories you want to remove it from and add some layout update xml to these specific categories.

I normally do this with statements like the following under Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories. Select the appropriate category and then click on Custom Design where you will find the Custom Layout Update field to out the XML in;

```
 <reference name="content">
     <remove name="masshead.blockname" />
 </reference>
```

You could go about it the other way and remove it from all categories by changing the layout xml file of the module to not include it and use layout update xml in the admin area per each category you want to include it on. Really depends on if there are more categories you want on it than not or vice versa.